Why do my messages on iMessage not get delivered?
I recently got a MacBook Pro 2019 that runs macOS 11. I can't message my friend on iMessage. I don't have an iPhone, so I just have an email linked to my account. I know that is enough to message people, but every single time, my messages just say "not delivered". I can't call him, I don't receive the messages he sends me. Yet, if he calls me on FaceTime, I receive it and I can talk to him. Any ideas?
